# Complex.java not accepted as a Java class in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have been using IntelliJ IDE for about a year, but I haven't faced this issue before.

I wanted to create a Complex class in Java to do operations with complex numbers. But, whenever I tried to create a Java class named **Complex.java**, I get this error :
[image]

The file icon is also different :
[image]

There is also no Java auto-completion support in that file and no **Run** option.

For this reason, I edited the Complex.java file in another editor and moved the file into the **src** folder. Still the same problem. Even if there are errors in that file, IntelliJ is not recognising them.

The other Java source files are working well and good, but IntelliJ is not accepting **only** the name **Complex.java**.

Why is this problem occurring and how to fix it?

Here is the whole screenshot of the IDE, in case you need it :
[image]

Comment: You can't name a class "Complex.java". You can name it "Complex", though, and IntelliJ will create a *file* named Complex.java.

Comment: Did you try changing the name of the file and running it?

Comment: You installed a plugin, probably called "TextMate" or "TextMate bundles", that is claiming priority as an editor of Java files. Uninstall or disable the plugin and see if it works then.

Comment: @CodeRider Yes, I tried changing the file name from `Complex` to `NComplex` and it is running well. Only the name **Complex** isn't accepted.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I tried what you said, I disabled the TextMate bundle, but still, there is an error. Now the error dialog shows `Unable to parse template "Class"
Error message: Selected class file name 'Complex.java' mapped to not java file type 'Text'`

Comment: Try to check if same name .class file is already there. Eg. if you are using eclipse or RAD, try crtl+shift+T and look for Complex.class

Comment: No, I didn't find any such thing.

Comment: Recently, I updated IntelliJ to the latest version with all settings resetted to defaults, and now, the file Complex.java is accepted as a Java class.

Comment: But, any idea, why was this happening?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by adding a wildcard to the registered patterns for java

Settings/Editor/File Types add Complex.java to File Name Patterns